# How do I generate a file M3U8 compatible with fmp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box, fmp4

I have a streaming solution that use MPEG-Dash protocol, and I would like to expose the same files on hls for IOS devices.

I read that fmp4 is now compatible with hls, so I thought that this could be done

When I generate may mpd file with this command:

`MP4Box -dash 33000 -frag 33000 -out video.mpd -profile dashavc264:onDemand original.mp4#audio original.mp4#video`

what I want is to not duplicate files, and use my generated Dash files with a HLS manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [this](https://github.com/DerouineauNicolas/gpac/tree/m3u8_mpd_rext) fork of gpac has experimental support for this. Also see this [ticket](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/772#issuecomment-360502733) - it has a link to a compiled gpac version from this branch and notes how to use it.

Comment: I try this branch, I had to compile it, bicause the links were down. ones I make it work the m3u8 file din't work with may player, this time I'm using this command: `MP4Box -frag 33000 -dash 33000 -profile dashavc264:onDemand original.mp4#video original.mp4#audio -m3u8-from-mpd output.m3u8 -out output.mpd`

Comment: Hmm, can you maybe post the generated m3u8 ? When you tried it out, did the player give any error info - like what exactly it is unable to fetch?

Comment: this is a file: `#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=639412,CODECS="avc1.64001E",RESOLUTION=640x480,AUDIO="audio"
output_1_1.m3u8

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="2",LANGUAGE="spa",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI=output_2_1.m3u8"` and the error that the player throw is: _GET http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/output_2_1.m3u8%22 404 (Not Found)_

Comment: I got it, the error is that the m3u8 file generated has a `"` extra character. but when I fix it the player simply does nothing, it don't even print a error

Comment: @Dop, sorry was off for the weekend. Does browser actually retrieve the m3u8 files and the underlying mp4 files? Maybe you can add the network tab screenshot and the m3u8 to your question? Is it publicly available so that we can inspect it?

Comment: no problem, I tried a nother app in the week end, Is [Shaka Packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager) it works like a charm. I will post the anwser later.

Comment: Do either of you know how to fix EXT-X-MAP:URI in m3u8 when specifying absolute hls_fmp4_init_filename using ffmpeg? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460212/470749 Thanks.